# PyQt4 Mdi sub window not resizing properly

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

In the following example, when you click the button, the entire form is rebuilt adding a new label each time. At the end is a resize call that doesn't appear to work. While debugging, I validated the `sizeHint()` is returning the correct dimensions, and internally the widget thinks it is the correct size, but what is drawn is not correct. What can I do to force the MDI window to resize correctly? Also of note, when not sized correctly, if you manually start resizing, it suddenly snaps to the appropriate size.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import PyQt4.Qt

class MdiWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.count = 0
        self.buildWindow()

    def buildWindow(self):
        main = QVBoxLayout()

        button = QPushButton('Change Count')
        button.clicked.connect(self.changeCount)
        main.addWidget(button)

        for i in range(self.count):
            main.addWidget(QLabel(str(i)))

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(main)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.resize(main.sizeHint())

    def changeCount(self, event):
        self.count += 1
        self.buildWindow()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Resize Test')
        self.mdiArea = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)

        child = MdiWindow()
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(child)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What happens if you make two calls to the resize method?

Comment: I posted the entire example, so you could try that for yourself, but no, that didn't help the issue

Comment: That's odd. By rights, your method should work without any user interaction. I would have assumed that by calling it twice, the first call would have "readied" the window for re-sizing. Having said that, python is not my strong suit.